# how to use Visual Studio 2003 on Windows 10 64bit 1703 update

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-10-v1703

So, I tried everything that I can but I cant seem to uninstall 1703 build on my PC, mainly due because of:

```
1) Group Policy - After I have uninstalled the update, it just comes back again.
2) I tried searching for "Go back to previous version of Windows 10" but this option is not available on the machine.
```

I have to also take note that this is a newly formatted computer, and have been sticking it with new updates for almost 24 hours now. I already installed Visual Studio 2003 on the computer but I cannot run the IDE. I have installed VS 2010, and VB6(and it works) on the said computer. Is there any possibility that I could run VS 2003 on a windows 10 1703 build?

Comment: If you do have Visual Studio 2010 installed and its working, whats the reason to install 2003 as well? Are you on a managed machine or do you have full control? Where is that GPO coming from?

Comment: Maybe you can use VS 2010 on Windows 10 1703, meanwhile, install a Windows 7 VM and run your VS 2003 on it.

In fact, VS 2010 including all features and functions of previous version, you don’t need to use VS 2003.

Comment: @Seth, there are some legacy programs that needs to be maintained still, I'm not sure if I have full control of the machine (unless I remove it from the domain)

Comment: @Origami Is that so? I did not know it until now! I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: @Origami I could, But the software becomes uncompatible with the DLL that comes with it, so I could not use this option. Another thing is I the software is used in 4 different countries.

Comment: Could you define "I cannot run the IDE"? I have successfully installed Visual Studio 2003 on Windows 10 x64 with the 1809 update. An issue I am having, is that none of the project Wizards work, but that may be due to trying to install the bare minimum components for C++ development. I can open and build existing projects just fine, though.

Comment: @TomLint That's basically it, I can't run the IDE. I can't open it, or load it, or start it. There is no response, I will try on this current build though, thank you!